# Display horizontal and vertical lines between tabs

Tags: html, css

we are displaying 4 tabs in a [site](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) as below image.

[image]

we want to display horizontal and vertical lines between each tabs as below image.

[image]

```js
window.changeTab = function(tabNum){
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs");
        for(i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tablinks[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
        tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("tab-text");
        for(i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
            tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" active","");
            if(i == tabNum){
                tabs[i].className += " active";
            }
        }
    }
```

```css
.tabs{
        display:inline-block;
        width:25%;
        float:left;
        height:45px;
        line-height:45px;
        cursor:pointer;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        color:#000000;
        font-size:19px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    .tabs:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .tabs.active{
        cursor:default;
  background:#ff7704;
    }
    .tabs.active:hover{
        text-decoration:none;
    }
    .tab-text{
        display:none;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        padding:0;
    }
    .tab-text.active{
        display:block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tabs active" onclick="changeTab(0)">Product Description</div>
    <div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(1)">Features</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(2)">Reviews</div>
<div class="tabs" onclick="changeTab(3)">Add Review</div>
    <div id="tab-1" class="tab-text active">
        <div class="next-content-product">

<h1>Product Description </h1>
<?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>

<div class="size-space">
<h1>Product Size & Space <span class="hidden-sku"><?php echo $_product->getSku();?></span> </h1>


<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('size_space');?>
</div>

                                
</div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2" class="tab-text">
        <div class="next-level-content-product">
<div class="interior-exterior">

<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('interior_exterior');?>
         
</div>
</div>  
    </div>
    <div id="tab-3" class="tab-text">   
    INSERT THIRD TAB CONTENT HERE       
    </div>
 
    <div id="tab-4" class="tab-text">    
    INSERT FOURTH TAB CONTENT HERE    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is magento ecommerce site.

Please help me to find solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any problem to do it with css child?

Comment: can you please help me how i can do with css child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding something like this maybe? (`#636363` seems to be the right color according to your [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html))

```
.tabs:first-child{
      border-left: 2px solid #636363;
}
.tabs{  
      border-right: 2px solid #636363;
      border-top: 2px solid #636363;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #636363;
}
```

Comment: thanks ,it worked fine. if you observe [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/beer-is-what-makes-you-see-double-and-feel-single-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html?___store=europe&___from_store=europe) , we are using same color for `add to cart` and `product description` but  `product description` is not displaying same background color , pls check here http://prnt.sc/bp0t9u

Comment: Are you sure? Background color is the same (#FF7704) for both `add to cart` and `product description`, (checked that with ColorZilla)

Comment: i am using this : `#ff7704;` i may be wrong, please give me what i need to use to display background color for `Product decription`

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask for. `product description` has already '#ff7704' as background. Do you want to change it? Maybe you want to change the border color instead? Please clarify.

Comment: if you check this : http://prnt.sc/bp0t9u  you can see background color looks different for both buttons. but i am using same color code for both. i dont know why that background-color of `product decription` looks different

Comment: Both seem the same orange to me, ColorZilla says it is the same too. Why don't you check it out with a color tool to remove any doubt?

Comment: okay than i checked with inspeact element in chrome. thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Your **tabs style** should go like this,

```
.tabs{
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
    height:45px;
    line-height:45px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:19px;
    text-align:center;
    border:solid 1px #111111;
    margin-right:-5px;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

[**Check this fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/zy1kbL9g/1/)